# Error executing remote Power Shell Script (Exchange 2010)

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I wrote a very small application, which access the Remote Power Shell of Exchanger Server 2010 SP1 and execute some scripts. Here is the sample code. Everything is in try and catch block.

```
  string insecurePassword = "mypassword";
  SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
  foreach (char passChar in insecurePassword.ToCharArray())
  {
   securePassword.AppendChar(passChar);
  }
  PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("mydomain\\administrator", securePassword);

  WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://exchange2010.domain.com/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
  connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
  Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
  PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
  PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
  ICollection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> results;


//The command I want to execute is Set-MailContact with some parameters.



    command.AddCommand("Set-MailContact");
    command.AddParameter("Identity", "SomeIdentityOfContact");
    command.AddParameter("EmailAddressPolicyEnabled", false);
    command.AddParameter("PrimarySmtpAddress", "myEmailAddress@domain.com");
    command.AddParameter("Confirm", false);
    command.AddParameter("Force", true);
    powershell.Commands = command;

    // open the remote runspace
    runspace.Open();
    // associate the runspace with powershell
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
    results = powershell.Invoke();
```

I am trying to set PrimarySmtpAddress of a MailContact, but for some reasons I am getting the following exception:

**System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'PrimarySmtpAddress'. Cannot convert value "SMTP:myEmailAddress@domain.com" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress"**

I think its must be due to serialization/de-serialization. Does someone have any idea on how to correctly pass the email address's value?

Any hint help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving off the SMTP: qualifier. That's already implicit in the -primarySMTPAddress parameter.

Comment: I'm not passing any SMTP Qualifier, can't you see that in my code? My concern is to set two email address for a MailContact. One is ExternalEmailAddress and other could be any. However, as far as I know we can only have one ExternalEmailAddress but which attribute I should use to set an additional email address

Comment: You can see this code which clearly shows I'm not adding SMTP qualified:    ~~command.AddParameter("PrimarySmtpAddress", "myEmailAddress@domain.com");~~

Comment: just realized the blunder I am doing. thanks for poiting it out ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing smtp server address with email address, try to pass something like smtp.yourcomapnydomain.com instead of such email address and test again.

Comment: I'm trying to set PrimarySmtpAddress of the MailContact. For example, myEmailAddress@domain.com is one of such address? What do you think should be the correct format, if I have to set an additional email address apart from an ExternalEmailddress?